# jquery Tabs loading Ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone help me figure out why the ajax content is not loaded in the following 
http://jsfiddle.net/nmsZX/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="casetabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/ajax/content1.html">Tab A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/ajax/content2.html">Tab B</a>
        </li>    
    </ul>        
</div>
```

Comment: Look at your console, you should see some red text containing something similar to *"ACCESS DENIED DUE TO SAME-ORIGIN POLICY"* Google that for more information.

Comment: how do i turn on the console?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: F12 is common shortcut for console

Comment: I am using Chrome. but i think i understood what you were saying. thanks!

Comment: In google chrome and firefox you simply press ctrl+shift+j, in Ie you press F12 (in ie, you have to reload the page after you open the console)

Answer (score 0):

Adding below piece of code in you code works

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $('#casetabs').tabs({remote: true}); 
});
</script>
```